# TypeError: object of type 'bool' has no len() in sys.argv length check

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

What is the reason for the error

```
TypeError: object of type 'bool' has no len()
```

Should i import something in my python program? I am using len(sys.argv) in if condition to check for the number of command line arguments, which are float values(like 1.2 and 2.4, etc). Any thoughts? This is in python2.6. This is how i am running the program

```
python BeaconsAnalysis.py 2.0 3.0
```

And some portion of my code where i am checking this is,

```
with open("luawrite", "r") as f:
    if(len(sys.argv == 2)):
            for line in f:
                    t1 = sys.argv[1]
                    t2 = sys.argv[2]
                    hashes = line.split()
                    t = hashes[0] 
                    ...........(goes on)
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant portion of your code, and what you're passing at the command line?

Comment: @BenLerner  I changed the code like you asked

Comment: Got my mistake. Sorry and Thank you.

Comment: I made the same mistake, so thanks for being the first google result!

Comment: Mods, you say "this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers" but I think you're underestimating how dumb some of us can be at times!

Answer (score 21):

You got the parens in the wrong place and need to account for the script name in argv[0]. `if(len(sys.argv == 2)):` should be `if(len(sys.argv) == 3):`

Comment: A stupid typo that I never make, except that, thanks to this answer, I checked and did find this very mistake that I had not been able to find though my unit test code was telling me about it. Thanks!

Comment: Just had exactly the same mistake... Seems we're all making them.

Comment: Exactly same error in my case too. It's funny after I read other comments to this answer. Thanks for this answer.